# where is getMessagesBlock() method located (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, register, persistent

### where is getMessagesBlock() method located (Magento 1.9)

I want to know where is the code of getMessagesBlock() method,

which is called in template:- **persistent/customer/form/register.phtml**

I want to customize the method and the messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find at two places where you can changes as per your requirements,

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
```

One Method is inside Compiler Module,

```
app/code/core/Mage/Compiler/Block/Process.php
```

You can override core method in local folder and do your changes.